# Why can't I access MEDIA_URL or MEDIA_ROOT on my urls.py file?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, backend

Just trying to add on to my path but when I try adding MEDIA_URL OR MEDIA_ROOT, it just doesn't want to appear. I don't know if there's another method to this. I'm on Django v4.1.7
urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('base.urls'))
] 
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static'
]

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'static/images'

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

[urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJdgJ.png)
[settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50Kdz.png)

I was expecting to for MEDIA_ROOT OR MEDIA_URL to appear right after 'settings.' but it didn't. All I want to do is extend the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are putting media files in the static folder; ideally, they go in a dedicated media folder.
However, the below should solve your issue.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
```

Comment: I'm just following a udemy tutorial, however, they use an older version of Django so I'm just trying to follow along. Your suggestion didn't work unfortunately. For some reason it's like MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT doesn't exist.

Comment: how should I go about doing it with a MEDIA folder? Would the code/setup be different if I used a media folder instead? I'm on Django v4.1.7 which is the latest version.

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "media"
MEDIA_URL = "/media/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you're putting your `MEDIA` folder inside your `STATIC`, that I don't know why. Are you using a latest version of Django?. Well, if you are, you can use this:

```
    MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR/"images"
```

Comment: That still didn't work. Every time I do settings.MEDIA_URL or settings.MEDIA_ROOT its like it's recognizing it as invalid code.  Since you're not the first to say it, how should I go about doing it with a MEDIA folder? Would the code/setup be different if I used a media folder instead? I'm on Django v4.1.7 which is the latest version.

Comment: Your `MEDIA` folder should be on its own, not inside the `STATIC` folder in the base directory, because that is how Django will know how to store and get files. Already your `urlpatterns` to the `MEDIA` folder is ok. 
```
`urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

```
Alternatively, you can create a `MEDIA` folder directly in your base folder/directory.